# Django nested requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have this function whch communicates with SWAPI API and I want to get species name for the movie.
So let's say I search 'New Hope', I have to get `['Hutt','Wookiee','Droid','Human','Rodian']` .
The problem is that in the SWAPI dict, you don't get the names ,you get a list of urls.

```
"species": [
        "https://swapi.co/api/species/5/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/species/3/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/species/2/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/species/4/"
    ],
```

This is my conde so far:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
    def search_films(request,title):
        context = {}
        species = []
        url = "https://swapi.co/api/?search=" + str(title)
        if request.method == "GET":
            r = requests.get(url)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                data = r.json()
                species = data['results'][0]['species']
                if species:
                    for species_url in species:
                        get_request = requests.get(species_url)
                        response_data = get_request.json()
                        species.append(response_data)
                    context['species'] = response_data
                    print(context)
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

At this point I get an error:

```
     raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '{'name': 'Hutt', 'classification': 'gastropod', 'designation': 'sentient', 'average_height': '300', 'skin_colors': 'green, brown, tan', 'hair_colors': 'n/a', 'eye_colors': 'yellow, red', 'average_lifespan': '1000', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/24/', 'language': 'Huttese', 'people': ['https://swapi.co/api/people/16/'], 'films': ['https://swapi.co/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.co/api/films/1/'], 'created': '2014-12-10T17:12:50.410000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:36:42.146000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.co/api/species/5/'}'
```

Any ideas of how to implement this?

Comment: *Where* do you get that error?

Comment: what is the result of `print(url)` if you insert it before `r = requests.get(url)`? Also print `species` variable

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I have corrected my question so you can see the url now. I get the error on ` get_request = requests.get(species_url)`

Comment: @Satevg  I have corrected my question so you can see the url now. Species variables returns the species urls I refer to in my question: `['https://swapi.co/api/species/5/', 'https://swapi.co/api/species/3/', 'https://swapi.co/api/species/2/', 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/', 'https://swapi.co/api/species/4/']
`

Comment: Obviously your "species_url" is not what you think it is - check the error message, what you're passing is not an url  :"'{'name': 'Hutt', 'classification': 'gastropod', 'designation': 'sentient', 'average_height': '300', 'skin_colors': 'green, brown, tan', (etc...)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, take a look at your line `species = []` You expect that there will be only urls, right? But it's not so, because you're appending to this list **response data** on this line: `species.append(response_data)`. During your script execution it becomes:

```
['https://swapi.co/api/species/5/',
 'https://swapi.co/api/species/3/',
 'https://swapi.co/api/species/2/',
 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/',
 'https://swapi.co/api/species/4/',
 {'name': 'Hutt', ....},
 {'name': 'Wookiee', ....}]
```

Because list is mutable data type. And on some iteration you're trying to fetch not url, but dictionary

I've made an attempt to fix your code renaming spices at the beginning of function to `species_data` and using this variable just for storing response from api(json response). spices urls are still in `spices` variable. I'm not sure if `return Response(species_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)` is correct logic for you, but you should get the idea. You need 2 *different* variables for urls and response data.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def search_films(request,title):
    context = {}
    species_data = []
    url = "https://swapi.co/api/?search=" + str(title)
    if request.method == "GET":
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            species = data['results'][0]['species']
            if species:
                for species_url in species:
                    get_request = requests.get(species_url)
                    response_data = get_request.json()
                    species_data.append(response_data)
                context['species'] = response_data
                print(context)
            return Response(species_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```